# Fine structure constant and unit conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, units, unit-conversion

In a paper I'm reading, the author writes down the following formula:
$$\Gamma=\dfrac{\alpha^2}{576\pi^3}\dfrac{\left(4+z\right)^2}{z}\dfrac{m^5}{m^2_\pi f_\pi^2}$$
$\Gamma$ is a function of $m$ (in MeV), and the rest are constants: $z=0.56$, $m_\pi=135$ MeV and $f_\pi=92$ MeV. These are explicitly stated, and I assume that $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant, with the usual value $\alpha=1/137$. The author then claims that
$$\Gamma=1.1\times 10^{-24}\text{ s}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{m}{\text{eV}}\right)^5$$
When I compute it, I get
$$\Gamma'=7.181\times 10^{-16}\text{ MeV}\left(\dfrac{m}{\text{MeV}}\right)^5=7.181\times 10^{-31}\text{ MeV}\left(\dfrac{m}{\text{eV}}\right)^5$$
Now I use the conversion
$$1\text{ eV}^{-1}=6.58\times 10^{-16}\text{ s}\Rightarrow 1\text{ MeV}=0.152\times 10^{19}\text{ s}^{-1}$$
to get $\Gamma'$ in s$^{-1}$
$$\Gamma'=1.09\times 10^{-12}\text{ s}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{m}{\text{eV}}\right)^5$$
And so my computation differs by twelve orders of magnitude from that of the article.

**Where did I go wrong?**

Comment: there is something fishy about the $1\ \mathrm{eV}\Rightarrow 1\ \mathrm{MeV}$...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The first equality is just $\hbar$ expressed in eV$\cdot$s, set to 1 (natural units) and inverted to get eV in terms of s. The second equality is the inverse of the first, multiplied by $10^3$ on both sides.

Comment: but $1\ \mathrm{eV}=10^{-\color{red}6}\ \mathrm{MeV}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes. As AccidentalFourierTransform pointed out, the coefficient $7.181\times 10^{-16}$, when converted from MeV to eV, should give $7.181\times 10^{-46}$. Mega means a million, and it to the fifth power gives $10^{30}$, not just $10^{15}$.

In this way, the OP has to add a $10^{-15}$ factor to his result. That makes his result $10^{-3}$ times the correct one.  There is another error which forces OP to add $10^{+3}$ to his result, thus getting to the right value. The correct conversion is
$$1\text{ eV}^{-1}=6.58\times 10^{-16}\text{ s}\Rightarrow 1\text{ MeV}=0.152\times 10^{22}\text{ s}^{-1}$$
Perhaps, I need to add an intermediate state, the inversion of the first formula, to make the result obvious:
$$1\text{ eV}=0.152\times 10^{+16}\text{ s}^{-1} $$
Again, one MeV is one million times, not one thousand times, larger than one eV, so the exponent turns to $22$, not $19$.

In total, he needs to add $-15+3$ orders of magnitude, thus reducing his result by an extra factor of $10^{-12}$.

Comment: It's very attractive to say that mega, $\text{M}$, is one thousand, because the lowercase $\text{m}$, or "milli", is one thousandth. ;-)

Comment: I think the main issue was that the majority of the papers I've been reading lately dealt with quantities in MeV or GeV (hence conversion factors of $10^{\pm 3}$) - that sneaky little eV took me by surprise :)

Comment: If you read e.g. articles about some X-rays relatively to the LHC, a TeV could get converted to a keV from the X-rays, and there would be $10^{6}$ there, too. But I understand your explanation why it happened, too.